# What happened to Siddhārtha Gautama wife Yashodhara?

Tags: vipassana, buddha, sangha

When Lord Buddha's wife Yashodhara also joined Sangha (become bhikkhuni), what happened to her ?

Did she also get enlightened ?

Did his son Rahula get enlightened ?

[This](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3324/9846), [This](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3326/9846) answers says **Buddha can never be a woman**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When Lord Buddha's wife Yashodhara also joined Sangha (become bhikkhuni), what happened to her ?

As part of the Bhikkhuni order nothing special or noteworthy incidents through the Buddha acknowledged her past contribution to his enlightenment in realising the [Parami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81ramit%C4%81).

And like anybody else she aged, decayed and passed away. On passing away she was truly free from suffering as she was enlightened.

> Did she also get enlightened ?

[Yasodharā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasodhar%C4%81) achieved enlightenment.

> Did his son Rahula get enlightened ?

[Rāhula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C4%81hula) also achieved enlightenment.

> ... says Buddha can never be a woman

A woman can never become a fully enlightened Buddha. But a woman can achieve enlightenment as a disciple nun. Yasodara became a disciple nun not a Buddha. She was the wife of Prince Siddhartha. She became a nun later in the Buddha's [Sasana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C4%81sana). Also see: [Bahu Dhātuka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/29.1a-Bahudhatuka-S-m115-piya.pdf)

Comment: Sir can you explain the edited question

Comment: See if this explains it.

Comment: A woman can never become a fully enlightened Buddha -- what is this?

Comment: See: Bahu Dhātuka Sutta

Comment: What's the difference fully enlightenment and normal enlightenment, i thought enlightenment is enlightenment.

Buddha means who realize self (its a simple hindi word).

Comment: Nirvana is same for all. A Buddha is one who rediscovers the teaching. A disciple ([Sāvaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka)) is one who learns from a Buddha or another disciple. A woman can be a [Sāvaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Ar%C4%81vaka) only. But a woman can aspire to be a Buddha but from the point you get the definite prophecy you would be a male.

Comment: (though it should be pointed out that unlike the rest of the Buddha's message, which repeats endlessly in the Pali Canon from different angles, the statement as to female Buddhahood is found once, so it is questionable!)

Comment: I do not want to debate this. I will go with what the Pali Cannon says until I have 1st hand knowledge on the matter. I would believe all who debate also do not have 1st hand knowledge so any views are just personal view and perhaps a shot in the dark.

Comment: Svâkkhato bhagavatâ dhammo sanditthiko akâliko ehipassiko opanâyiko paccattam veditabbo viññuhiti, doesn't leave room for denying any conscious and reasoned being from discovering the Dhamma by themselves. The ability to teach and also be listened to though, I accept, is influenced by social norms!

Comment: 'no woman can be a Buddha' is also an Essential line in the sand. This goes against anicca and anatta.

Comment: Out of the 3 Characteristics the 1st 2 (anicca, dukkha) pertain to what is **conditioned** and the last (anatta) to all Dhamma. Anicca does not effect the laws of nature. Laws of nature are not impermanent. If this was the case the Buddha would have said all Dhamma is anicca.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least three suttas to Rahula:

[MN 61](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh033-u.html)

[MN 62](http://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Texts-and-Translations/Short-Pieces/MahaRahulovadasuttam.htm)

[MN 147](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn147)

Yasodharā is mentioned as 'Baddha Kaccānā', having great wisdom in [AN 1.245](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/4Anguttara-Nikaya/Anguttara1/1-ekanipata/014-Etadaggapali-e.html)