# Why the first of the additional rules, put forward by lord Buddha, on Bikkhunis?

Tags: monk, vinaya

I've learned that Lord Buddha has put forward 7 rules on Bikkhunies when female were given the permission to enter the shasana as Bikkhunies. Maha Prajapathee devi & the other princesses were given the permission to be Bikkhunies after agreeing to live accordingly.

There is one rule which I really don't undersatnd why Lord Buddha chanted; "Bikkhunies should worship monks who even became a monk on that very day, even though the Bikkhuni is elder in Bikkuni life". As a great philosoper who said men to treat women equally, I really wonder why this rule is put forward by Lord Buddha. Monks are always asked to worship another monk based on the time period lived as a monk.

One day during a Dhamma deshana I heard a thero chanting that these rules were added later into Buddhism, by Brahmins, to show that Lord Buddha didn't give equal right to women, which was a practice in their community.
Can someone please clarify this to me?

May the noble triple gem bless you!