# In regard of what or whom are you loyal?

Tags: personal-practice, faith, wisdom

Ven. Members of the Sangha (of Bhikkhus), Ven. fellows, valued Upasaka and Upasika, dear readers and interesed,

This question is intellectual and theoretical, or literary, but also/merely inviting self-reflection; but of course it can also be answered with words of the Buddha in "should-form" (in the later case, exchange "you" with "a serious follower of the Buddha, a person in general, to find peace", how ever you wish and feel obligated or loyal to).

So, about loyalty,

- In regard of what are you able to claim being loyal?
- Whom are you loyal to?
- How far goes your loyalty?
- Where and how does it end?

Also, finally:

- What must one be loyal to, to find, to reach the highest aim all Buddha-following seekers are after?
- What are you loyal and/or are you not loyal to, so that you have't found final peace already, or you highest desired goal?
- What is an Arahat loyal to? Has loyality, then, an end (no more required)?

Maybe you try to give a loyal answer.

Much joy and inside in giving a benefical answer, at least for youself.

Comment: Perhaps this question is related to the statement recently posted [in this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22203/254), which says that people "generally have actually no respect in regard of the Jewels and put their own developed values above it: do not go for refuge = putting one self under an authority".

Comment: It did not originated there, although it was addressed after this answer, if that was one thought of Nyom @ChrisW . Actually like always, the question was made after the though "What could bring the eager knowledge exchanger here to selfreflection, encouraging to practice" like all answers are also motivated, if wishing to know it's origin. As if related: at the heartwood, yes. All questions and answers of my person are related and loyal intented to a single goal and welfare with it.

Comment: seems to be an opinion based question only

Answer (score 1):

Generally Buddhist take refuge in Buddha, Dhamma, and Sangha.
In that regard, I would say I support Sangha. Because they protect Dhamma. Which helps to attain Buddhahood. Generally, Sangha means Ariya Sangha. But here I meant any person who can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Nyom Sarath, that means your admirable friend, your teachers, or maybe better aid, those you think that they lead you in the right direction, is that right? Would that at the end, just in that way expressed, not mean that Sarath does the same like everyone? E.g. is loyal to his believes that it leads in the right direction. Maybe that "counter-question" leads to maybe deeper reflection or to a maybe deeper and more secure guiding answer. It has not to be seen as critic but as an invitation. Those are really challencing questions, not quick to answer & good reflexions to counter certain things.

Comment: Right direction means Nibbana my ultimate goal. My objective is to realise Nibbana.

Comment: Saddhu! (Maybe Sarath likes to add this importand loyality to strive, chanda) That means you are loyal to your intent of liberation and all that looks like that it leads to it. But doesn't that allow the same conter-questions?

Comment: Let my person ask different: What is Sarath loyal and not loyal to, that he had not reached his aim already?

Answer (score 1):

> **self-reflecting...**

*Atta-manasikara-self-reflecting*.

> **In regard of what are... able to claim being loyal?**

Anatta ([SN 22.59](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.mend.html)). Sunnata ([SN 35.85](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.085.than.html)). Lokuttara dhamma ([SN 20.7](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn20/sn20.007.than.html)).

> **Whom are... loyal to?**

The ignorance-created idea of "who" is properly negated in [SN 12.12](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.012.nypo.html)

> **How far goes... loyalty?**

Anatta. Sunnata. Nibbana. Vimutti

> **Where and how does it end?**

[MN 29](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn29) & 30 state the holy life has *ceto-vimutti* (liberation of mind) as its final end (*pariyosāna*).

Answer (score 1):

Everyone who can give me the whole 6 benefits: 1)own benefit, 2)other benefits, 3)public benefit, 4)this life benefit, 5)next life benefit, and 6)nibbāna benefit.

**Everyone** mean I try listen everyone.

**The whole** mean I trust in no separate benefits.

Infinity, until I will parinibbāna.

Comment: Sadhu, Nyom Warapol, great to resove "Everyone mean I try listen everyone" and stay open minded, without preoccupation, and nice collection. May my person ask where it comes from, seems to been commentary, right? My person aslo wonders a little about public benefit, (other means beings of all realm, animal, devas... petas...)? Only if all is served best, great. Also mudita that Nyom enjoyes to share Dhamma here and that he is well respected. Great that not Greatings to Bangkok and you Dhamma-friends. Translate as much as possible from commentary and share, best first to the Sangha.

Answer (score 0):

If I ever knew , I forgotten many times before remembering.
I forget and get caught up into the world. I suppose I am loyal to the world but more and more I am loyal to the naked truth of the Dhamma.

On the frontlines of the world is were learning is, right in the defilement! I don't know if I need a monastery. I don't always need to aim for a tranquil state of mind.