# Online reference to AA.i.254

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for an online reference to **AA.i.254** mention at the bottom of [this page](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/c/cakkavatti.htm):

> No woman can become a Cakka-vatti (the reasons for this are given at AA.i.254).

Either an English or Sinhala translation would be preferable

Comment: Per the [List of Abbreviations](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/abreviations.htm), "AA" might be "Manorathapūranī, Anguttara Commentary, 2 vols. (S.H.B.)."

Answer (score 2):

Per the [List of Abbreviations](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/abreviations.htm), "AA" might be "Manorathapūranī, Anguttara Commentary, 2 vols. (S.H.B.)."

[This catalog](http://www.worldcat.org/title/manorathapurani-buddhaghosas-commentary-on-the-anguttata-nikaya/oclc/470510249/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true) claims that:

- The editions are mostly Print books (English or Pali)
- There are some eBooks in Pali from the PTS

I don't know that (I doubt whether, but I haven't searched) there's an edition free online.

Google Books shows a limited preview of e.g. the Pali eBooks (e.g. [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Manorathap%C5%ABran%C4%AB.html?id=WkkFAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y)).

Comment: It'd be convenient to have an online link, if not i'll check it out the next time I visit a library. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Can you try using a Sinhalese search term? That might find something that I couldn't.

Comment: The Sinhalese term is 'මනෝරථපූරනී', but there are no downloadable versions

Answer (score 0):

Sutta. Ma. U. Papañcasūdanī-Atthakatha, [Bahudhātukasuttavaṇṇanā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=10&A=2214&h=sabbamanussehi,adhiko,attabh%C4%81vo)'s translation :

> The description of "[It is impossible that a woman should be the Universal Monarch](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=14&item=234&items=13&eng=metta_e)": Because the woman can't grow with [The Thirty Two Marks of a Great Man](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/v.php?B=11&A=3182&Z=3922&eng=suttacentral), such as Phimosis, etc. [The woman can't has seven gems](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=19&A=2984&eng=suttacentral), such as woman-gem (the precious woman). The woman's body can't be the biggest body of all human. So, Buddha said " [It is impossible that a woman should be the Universal Monarch](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=14&item=234&items=13&eng=metta_e)".

---

*Actually, I don't want to answer like below because the feminists have resisted me before on my reply of some topic like this. I never want to attack anyone, buddha as well.*

Sutta. Ma. U. [Bahudhātukasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=14&item=234&items=13&eng=metta_e):

> Whatever fears, misfortunes and dangers arise, they all arise from the foolish not from the wise ... Therefore bhikkhus, to become wise inquirers, you should train thus.
>
> ...
>
> “Venerable sir, saying it rightly how is the bhikkhu clever in the possible and impossible.” ... It is impossible that a **woman** should be the Universal Monarch It is possible that a **man** should be the Universal Monarch.
>
> ...
>
> “Ānanda, call it, the Discourse on many elements, or The fourfold circle, or The mirror of the Teaching, or The drum of deathlessness, or **The noble victory in the battle**.”

That context is the same of [Sun Tzu](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sun_Tzu)'s clauses:

> if you know your enemies and know yourself, you will not be imperiled in a **hundred battles**; you will not be imperiled in a hundred **battles**; if you do not know your enemies but do know yourself, you will **win** one and **lose** one; if you do not know your enemies nor yourself, you will be imperiled in every single **battle**.

**[The context](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=14&item=234&items=13&eng=metta_e) is about the best no.1 winner (cakka-vatti/buddha/arahanta/etc.,) vs the ordinary (the follower).** So, we have to look about **the qualification of the best no.1 winner**.

**Remember**: Buddhism never against female to be the best, if **everything** (everything is everything, everything is not something) of them can compare to the male. But by the science, history, environment, etc., it  is quite harder than the male.

### So, what is the qualification of the best no.1 winner?

1. The best physical body.
2. The best  I.Q.
3. The best  E.Q.
4. The best  M.Q.
5. The best  Teacher.
6. The best  practice.
7. The best  effort.
8. The best  environment.
9. Etc.

### Then answer me for these questions to get the answer of this topic:

Don't let me answer it by myself, because I can be killed by the feminists.

1. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best physical body compare to the other period of month?
2. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best I.Q. compare to the other period of month?
3. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best E.Q. compare to the other period of month?
4. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best M.Q. compare to the other period of month?
5. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best Teacher compare to the other period of month?
6. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best practice compare to the other period of month?
7. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best effort compare to the other period of month?
8. On menstrual period of every month, does a female has the best environment compare to the other period of month?
9. **How many time of a life, that the male has bloody period?**
10. How are the patients feeling when they lost their nutriment for bloody lesion?  While this situation, how are their I.Q., E.Q., M.Q., effort, etc.?
11. How are the patients feeling when they stomachache by the bloody intestine?   While this situation, how are their I.Q., E.Q., M.Q., effort, etc.?
12. **How the doctors, psychiatrist, etc., answer my question?**
13. Why Olympic separates the female competition from the male competition?
14. Etc.

**Remember**: Buddhism never against female to be the best, if **everything** (everything is everything, everything is not something) of them can compare to the male. But by the science, history, environment, etc., it  is quite harder than the male.

---

Actually, it is from tipitaka, Sutta. Ma. U. [Bahudhātukasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=14&item=234&items=13&eng=metta_e) ,  not atthakatha:

> It is impossible that a woman should be the Universal Monarch It is possible that a man should be the Universal Monarch.

It is from Mahidol University Application Budsir  The Pali Tipitaka in Roman Character Volume 20 page 36-37.

http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=20&A=738

[Click here](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_read.php?B=14&A=3481&w=Bahudh%26%23257%3Btukasutta%26%237747%3B_ni%26%237789%3B%26%237789%3Bhita%26%237747%3B_pa%26%23241%3Bcama%26%237747%3B.&modeTY=1) for these versions of this sutta: Siamrattha(THAI), Mahaculalonkorn University, Atthakatha Pali, and Thai translation of Atthakatha by Mahamakut University.

Comment: It says "the reasons for this are given at AA.i.254". But Bahudhātuka sutta merely repeats the statement. Reasons are not given. I'm guessing the reasons/explanation is in the commentary.

Comment: I think the OP's question is not about the sutta, but about the reasons for that a woman can't be a universal monarch. And, apparently those reasons are given in AA.i.254, not the sutta itself.

Comment: @Sankha Kulathantille Is it better?

Comment: @Bonn I'm looking for a reference of AA.i.254. Possibly an English translation of the Pali commentary. Not personal opinions.

Comment: **Haven't you ever watched any competition?** It already described by the syntax of  Bahudhātukasuttaṃ which I quoted above. Therefore, the pali translation of commentary have nothing, so I wasted my time to describe you by myself. It is common sense of what I described, everyone can describe it by themselves, so the commentary never describe it before.

Comment: Another, commentary wrote "they describe only the hard words of tipitaka", so the ability of female is not the commentary's job to describe.  If buddha said "female can't be the Universal Monarch", you have to ask the scientist for the reason why most female have a few wininig the competition/war/fight when compare to the male. If you ask commentary, they will said because the female doesn't have enough qualification. Then you have to go back to ask the scientist again. So, it is not the question for the commentary. It is the question for the scientist.

Comment: I added the translation. Is it what you want?

Comment: @Bonn That translation in the first paragraph comes close to what i'm looking for, but I don't think  it's AA.i.254. Your effort is not in vain. I have given you +1 ;)

Comment: See also [Can the Buddha ever be a woman?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3322/254)

Comment: It is the copy of each other, no any word difference. But I choose in MN because it come with context. You can compare it's pali to see they are the same. Manorathaurani: 
 http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/read_rm.php?B=14&A=9920&w=Itth%26%23299%3Brata&modeTY=1 , Papancasudani : http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=10&A=2214&h=sabbamanussehi,adhiko,attabh%C4%81vo

Comment: @ChrisW Their answers in that topic look bias to the historian, and religious. No one bases on science. And if you compare them with my answers, commentary which I quoted, and especially bahudhātukasutta's context, you going to see the sciences and evidences basis answer.

Comment: One of the answers in that topic was mine (and I'm not persuaded by the "scientific" and "evidence-based" questions/argument you proposed in your answer here).

Comment: @ChrisW I don't want to rude. I just want to share the way I study pali canons. I can say nothing conflict in tipitaka by this way. And I often wrote "the western study system let tipitaka conflict each others". That's why I often compare the westerners' answers with my answers. I don't want to be superego. I just try to support the westerner to deconflict pali canons. I am sorry, If I wrote something looks terrible.

Comment: I'm grateful that you take the time to share your understanding of the suttas, in your answers to questions here; and I hope that people find your answers helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. I am practicing to talk by english for almost a year. I hope my conversation skill will better soon to understand people and tolet people understand tipitaka.