# What motivates a fully awakened person in a loving relationship?

Tags: reference-request, sutras, relationship, personal-experience

Loving relationship here is meant specifically as a mutually intimate partnership like husband and wife and boyfriend and girlfriend. There would be the case where one would become fully awake and therefore abandons all teachings but whilst still in a relationship. Would this change the dynamics of that relationship in some major way?

What do the Suttas say about this if anything?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unfolding", but it's nearly impossible if not impossible that an Arahant has any interest in an intimate partnership. Even a non-returner has no interest because they enjoy the pleasures of Jhana. Also, both have ended sensual desire, so there is i) no interest in a partnership, and ii) one has much higher pleasures than that derived from a partner. Unfolding into Arahant while being in a relationship is very hard, because one must abandon all craving, and if past sankharas are with craving due to being in a relationship, I fail to see the connection to Arahantship.

Comment: Val you can write that as an answer

Comment: @Val - I don't know how to term it - unfold, fall into, fall out of...

Comment: You made two changes: "fully enlightened" instead of "arahant", and "personal-experience" instead of reference-request". Three problems: 1) ask this as a new or follow-on question instead, and leave this one as-is, to avoid "invalidating" the existing answers? 2) not clear what "fully-enlightened" is compared to "arahant" (maybe less exclusive to Theravada and more inclusive of Mahayana); 3) implies/requires that to answer it people be (or have personal experience of being) fully-enlightened - maybe ask "what's an enlightened motive" or "what motive might a relatively enlightened person have".

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I understand that you're asking me to define a group - implicitly. Also, I'm not content with the other suggestion of rephrasing the question as a separate question. I'm not comfortable in doing either or both of these and so in this case I would request that you take the question down to avoid the confusion that you anticipate.

Comment: I'll leave it as-is; but people who have already answered might not change their existing answers to reply to the new question -- also IMO the new question is difficult to answer if (as I assume they may be) people are reluctant and/or unable to speak from personal experience of a "fully awakened" person and in a loving relationship at that (I thought that "relatively" might possibly be more answerable from personal experience than "fully", though apparently such comparisons might be seen as [conceit](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9424/254) by definition).

Answer (score 3):

***Remark:*** This is not (yet?) a full answer, but more an extended comment.

For one impression of how might a loving relation be revered see  ["A.IV. 55 Nakulapitá und Nakulamátá"](https://suttacentral.net/an4.55/en/sujato) ; although the couple is not called arahants they are mentioned as "top on lay disciples" (see ["A I.24"](https://suttacentral.net/an1.248-257/en/sujato))  *"The foremost of my laymen ...(...) ... who are intimate is the householder Nakula’s father.”*
So there's no right-out disregard of being a loving couple.

Next it might be interesting a story about the (later) arahant (Maha) Kassapa about the problem of being married and having a desire for ascetic life at the same time. Hellmuth Hecker has compiled a story about this which I found some time ago at the access-to-insight site (I think) . Here is a part of that text on the biographic tale about Kassapa:

> (...) Like the two chief disciples, Sariputta and Maha Moggallana, Maha
>   Kassapa too descended from the brahmin caste, and again like them, he
>   was older than the Buddha. He was born in the Magadha country, in the
>   village Mahatittha, as the son of the brahmin Kapila and his wife
>   Su-manadevi.
>
> *(This account of Maha Kassapa's early life is taken from the commentary to the Samyutta Nikaya.)*
>
> He was called Pipphali. His father owned sixteen villages over which he ruled like a
>   little king, so Pipphali grew up in the midst of wealth and luxury.
>   Yet already in his young years there was in him the wish to leave the
>   worldly life behind, and hence he did not want to marry. When his
>   parents repeatedly urged him to take a wife, he told them that he
>   would look after them as long as they live, but that after their
>   deaths he wanted to become an ascetic. Yet they insisted again and
>   again that he take a wife, so to comfort his mother he finally agreed
>   to marry -- on the condition that a girl could be found who conformed
>   to his idea of perfection. For that purpose he shaped a golden statue
>   of a beautiful woman, had it bedecked with fine garments and
>   orna-ments, and showed it to his parents, saying: *"If you can find a
>   woman like this for me, I shall remain in the home life."*
>
> His parents approached eight brahmins, showered them with rich gifts,
>   and asked them to take the image with them and travel around in search
>   of a human likeness of it. The brahmins thought: "Let us first go to
>   the Madda country, which is, as it were, a gold mine of beautiful
>   women." There they found at Sagala a girl whose beauty equaled that of
>   the image. She was Bhadda Kapilani, a wealthy brahmin's daughter, aged
>   sixteen, four years younger than Pipphali Kassapa.
>
> Her parents agreed to the marriage proposal, and the brahmins returned to
>   tell of their success.
>
> Yet Bhadda Kapilani also did not wish to marry, as it was her wish,
>   too, to live a religious life as a female
>   ascetic. Such identity between her aspiration and Pipphali Kassapa's
>   may well point to a kammic bond and affinity between them in the past,
>   maturing in their present life and leading to a decisive meeting
>   between them and a still more decisive separation later on.
>
> When Pipphali heard that what he had thought most unlikely had actually
>   occurred, he was -- unhappy and sent the following letter to the girl:
>   *"Bhadda, please marry someone else of equal status and live a happy
>   home life with him. As for myself, I shall become an ascetic. Please
>   do not have regrets."*
>   Bhadda Kapilani, like-minded as she was,
>   independently sent him a similar letter.
>   But their parents,
>   suspecting such an exchange would take place, had both letters
>   intercepted on the way and replaced by letters of welcome. So Bhadda
>   was taken to Magadha and the young couple were married. However, in
>   accordance with their ascetic yearning, both agreed to maintain a life
>   of celibacy. To give expression to their resolve, they would lay a
>   garland of flowers between them before they went to bed, determined
>   not to yield to sensual desire. This young wealthy couple lived thus
>   happily and in comfort for many years. As long as Pipphali's parents
>   lived, they did not even have to look after the estate's farms. But
>   when his parents died, they took charge of the large property.
>   (...)

Now,  further after the death of Pipphali's parents, Pipphali and also Baddha took the yellow robe and left home, but walked together. Then this happened:

> (...) When walking on, Kassapa went ahead while Bhadda followed behind
>   him.    Considering this, Kassapa thought: "Now, this Bhadda Kapilani
>   follows    me close behind, and she is a woman of great beauty. Some
>   people -    could easily think, 'Though they are ascetics, they still
>   cannot live    without each other! It is unseemly what they are
>   doing.' If they spoil    their minds by such wrong thoughts or even
>   spread false rumors, they    will cause harm to themselves." So he
>   thought it better that they    separate. When they reached a
>   crossroads Kassapa said: "Bhadda, you    take one of these roads, and
>   I shall go the other way." She said: "It    is true, for ascetics a
>   woman is an obstacle. People might think and    speak badly about us.
>   So please go your own way, and we shall now    part."
>   She then
>   respectfully circumambulated him thrice, saluted him    at his feet,
>   and with folded hands she spoke: "Our close companionship    and
>   friendship that had lasted for an unfathomable past comes to    an
>   end today. Please take the path to the right and I shall take the 
>   other road." Thus they parted and went their individual ways, seeking 
>   the high goal of Arahatship, final deliverance from suffering.
>   It is
>   said that the earth, shaken by the power of their virtue, quaked and 
>   trembled.

---

*From: MAHA KASSAPA: FATHER OF THE SANGHA by Hellmuth Hecker
Revised and enlarged translation from the German by Nyanaponika Thera*

*Translated and adapted from //Wissen und Wandel// XXI, 6 (1975)
Wheel Publication No. 345
Copyright 1987, 1995 Buddhist Publication Society*
                      BUDDHIST PUBLICATION SOCIETY
                      KANDY              Sri Lanka

---

So here we find something like "platonic love" between ascetics but in this instance much deeper, Hecker proposes the expression "karmic bond" for something which we might assume as an exotic example for a very deep arrangement of love over an already long chain of rebirthes...

Comment: This is a very interesting answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to Nakula's father

Answer (score 2):

I think even an anagami would stop being interested in relationships because sensual desire is one of the fetter that is removed at non return. So an anangami and arahant are likely to leave the house and become monks. If the anagami has a wife or a husband before attaining non return then they will probably live as sister or brother and not as husband and wife.

> Milindapanha III.19
>
> "You say that if a layman attains arahantship he must either enter the Order that very day or die and attainparinibbàna. Yet if he is unable to find a robe and bowl and preceptor then that exalted condition of arahantship is a waste, for destruction of life is involved in it."
>
> "The fault does not lie with arahantship but with the state of a layman, because it is too weak to support arahantship. Just as, O king, although food protects the life of beings it will take away the life of one whose digestion is weak; so too, if a layman attains arahantship he must, because of the weakness of that condition, enter the Order that very day or die."

So an arahant wouldn’t be able to live as a layman for long. I don’t remember which sutta but in that sutta the Buddha or someone said that arahant can only stay as layman for 7 days or they must enter Parinibanna.

Love is sensual desire and an anagami and arahant would completely be free of sensual desire so they won’t have a reason to stay in a relationship with his or her girlfriend. So love relationship is not possible for anagamis and arahants

Comment: `Love is sensual desire` -- But doesn't Buddhism identify any different kinds of "love"? Including *metta* ("loving-kindness") for example, or *karuna* ("compassion")?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how this works for Eckhart Tolle and Adyashanti both of whom have partners. Maybe they're in the stream still.

Comment: Metta is a different kind of love. Most ordinary wordings think that love is good. But it is attachment + sensual desire. Loving kindness is also impermanent. It is mentioned in a few suttas.

Comment: I don’t believe any layman who claim to be arahant unless they are planning to ordain asap

Comment: You don't really believe that tolle is enlightened, do you? Not to be rude, but who understands his talks? I believe he doesn't understands his talks either

Comment: I don’t even know him. Most wordlings think that “enlightenment” is becoming omniscience or something like that but in fact true enlightenment is fading of passion and 10 fetters. I also think that sadhguru only have worlding wisdom.

Comment: @Val - I don't know. How would one know? It seems he still has sense desires and that might be telling of a non-attainment.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it would be *karuna*, compassion.

There's a Zen story, [Is that so?](http://www.101zenstories.org/is-that-so/) -- probably not that "Zen master Hakuin" is counted an arahant, but I guess the motive displayed in that story is compassion.

Anyway I think we're told that the Buddha's own motive, per [MN 26](https://suttacentral.net/mn26/en/sujato):

> Then, understanding Brahmā’s invitation, I surveyed the world with the eye of a Buddha, because of my **compassion** for sentient beings.
>   *Atha kho ahaṃ, bhikkhave, brahmuno ca ajjhesanaṃ viditvā sattesu ca **kāruññataṃ** paṭicca buddhacakkhunā lokaṃ volokesiṃ*.

The motive presumably or by definition wouldn't be "sensuality", however.

And it's [Theravada orthodoxy](https://dhammawiki.com/index.php/Lay_arahant#Arahant_Lay_followers) that any lay arahant must join the Order immediately.

Even if we assume no craving for sensuality, I'm not sure what you mean by "mutually intimate" in the question -- that phrase suggests to me some self-view (e.g. "I love you and you love me") -- perhaps these are part of a "thicket of views", which no longer bind an enlightened being.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "it's Theravada orthodoxy" do you mean it is unique to Theravada and thus a view not shared by the wider context of Buddhism?

Comment: Theravada Buddhism have the view that an arahant would be completely free of lust, hatred and delusion so they wouldn’t need to stay in their house anymore. I would say that an anagami would become an monk unless he has a mother or father who is old. If he has a mother or father then he might work simple jobs like selling pots. There was an anagami who sold pots. I don’t remember which sutta.

Comment: @Suchness I think I know [even] less about the orthodoxy of other schools of Buddhism than I do of Theravada's interpretation of the Pali canon. I suspect/expect there are some differences, but I'm ill-equipped to describe them accurately. Your saying "[Arahant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arhat)" in the question may imply you were asking for a Theravada-like view, perhaps Mahayana have (or some may have, or have had) a different view of what an Arahant is and what Enlightenment is, what the stages of enlightenment are, and so on ...

Comment: ... I think the "stages of enlightenment" per the Pali suttas are as listed in an overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetter_(Buddhism)) -- which is why people answer "no sensuality" etc. -- and SFAIK that's not the same as the Mahayana-defined stages. I do think that the Buddha, though, might be considered (or defined as) an Arahant (and perhaps more than just an Arahant), so I think I'm not wrong to quote MN 26 in this answer.

Comment: @Chris & TheDBSGuy - I see. With regards to orthodoxy this is probably where I alight and have a rummage around inside using some sort of self-directed intuition. Thanks.

Comment: @Suchness We could chat if you wanted to, or ask another question. I guess the Buddha famously left his family (and they joined the Order later). Are there are Stream-winner states, as you mentioned, attainable to lay people -- Arahant might be quite usual. I'm not sure I agree (nor disagree) with all Theravada orthodoxy e.g. from my own experience, [this for example](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3336/254) and that kind of doctrinal detail. Mahayana also has some "Buddha nature" doctrine which might be relevant to your question but that I'm not well-informed to tell you about.

Comment: @Suchness More generally (per Theravada again), *karuna* (compassion) is one of the four *Brahmaviharas*, which are said to be the right attitude in (i.e. some solution for) all social situations -- worth investigating all four, probably, e.g. because an excess of one might be balanced by some of another.

Comment: @Suchness And/or if you were saying that don't want to ask what's orthodox but only hear from people's own experience, you might have to rephrase the question (because to answer *that*, someone would have to claim to be an Arahant or to know one). One of the guidelines for answering question on SE is that answers should be "backed up" either with references or from personal experience. Also you explicitly asked for references e.g. with the [tag:reference-request] tag.

Comment: @Chris - thanks for the invitation to chat. I read your answer to 'Can The Buddha ever be a women' several days ago which I found fascinating. Yes, references are helpful as general directional pointers but in your own words, they are all [somebody's] interpretations; somebody's views. It seems 80-90% of 'waking-up' comes from personal-direction or at least this is what I'm finding with myself. I will look at changing the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for a monk whose mental fermentations are ended to engage in sexual intercourse. ([AN 9.7](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an09/an09.007.than.html))

Comment: What about sadness and displeasure regarding external events?

Comment: Arahant experiences pleasant and unpleasant sense contacts. Refer to Iti 44: https://suttacentral.net/iti44/en/ireland

Comment: I'm asking because Maha Boowa cried in one of his talks. I wasn't referring to sense contact. It is obvious that the body cannot circumvent pleasant and unpleasant experiences.

Comment: Apologies for the roundabout reference, I am searching for the direct text, but in a talk to Anathapindika, the Buddha is said to have said (this is a reference to a quote): "Anathapindika came a little closer to the supramundane reality, since the Enlightened One explained that the arahants were always well, for they were beyond all possibilities for suffering.", as found in https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/hecker/wheel334.html .. If anyone has the sutta reference, would be appreciated, thanks in advance!